# Math.max.apply method and spread (...) function returning Infinity/NaN when processing an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, spread

I am using the Math.max function to process an array using the spread function, but am still receiving a NaN error. Any help into this matter would be greatly appreciated.

```
import finnhub from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/finnhub';



const api_key = finnhub.ApiClient.instance.authentications['api_key'];
api_key.apiKey = "c5cam0iad3ib55bb0ajg"
const finnhubClient = new finnhub.DefaultApi()

let stockTicker = prompt("Please enter the symbol of the stock to chart:");


//Finance API Function Call Below
finnhubClient.stockCandles(stockTicker, "D", ((Math.trunc(Date.now() / 1000)) - 8640000), Date.now(), (error, data, response) => {

  
let dataSetDayHigh = []
let dataSetDayRange = 1
  
  for (dataSetDayRange = 1; dataSetDayRange < 41; dataSetDayRange = dataSetDayRange + 1){
    dataSetDayHigh[dataSetDayRange] = Math.trunc(data.h[dataSetDayRange])
  }
  
  
let yAxisRangeUpper = Math.max.apply(null, dataSetDayHigh)
  console.log("Data Set Day High Values = " + yAxisRangeUpper)
```

Comment: What is the data in your array?

Comment: I don't see spread syntax anywhere in the code posted.

Comment: It seems you have a sparse array, since you start from index 1. Giving such an array to `Math.max` is the same a giving it `undefined` which, in turn, will produce `undefined`. Why exactly do you have a sparse array and can you not build a normal one?

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I have changed the array counter to start from zero and am being returned my intended result.